# Утечка памяти при использований хандлер

Tags: java, android, android-handler

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("" + 666);
    }
}, 10000);
```

Пишу такой код в `OnClickListener`. Наслышан о проблеме утечки памяти при хандлерах. Как конкретно при этом коде устранить проблему утечки памяти? Или хандлер сам умрет и освободит память после 10 000 миллисекунд?

Answer (score 1):

[здесь](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) довольно подробно расписано, и решение тоже.

Если вкратце - (как и написано в линте) In Java, non-static inner and anonymous classes hold an implicit reference to their outer class. То есть `Runnable` будет держать ссылку на активити (через хендлер) а течение времени указанного в параметре `postDelayed` (а потом освободит ссылку и gc сможет сработать).

Comment: Это означает что мне не стоит волноваться насчет утечки памяти? Я параллельно задал вопрос в других форумах. Там ребята вовсю уверенный, что будут проблемы с утечкой памяти.

Comment: Зависит от ситуации, от кода в run(). Если там view например, стоит проверять их состояние, активити может быть убита в то время как будет исполняться этот код, или если это фрагмент то он будет отсоединен уже. Для подстраховки можно создать класс MyHandler как в приведенной ссылке

Comment: У меня в телe run вместо textView.setText("" + 666); вызывается другая процедура